# Is there an INSERT or UPDATE equivalent to PDO::FETCH_CLASS?

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, sql-update

I have found the `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` very useful. My classes map to tables. I just do a

```
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM fixedTime WHERE
                  transmissionProgramID = '$transmissionProgramID'");
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'FixedTime');
```

and voila.

I would like to be able to do the reverse: ie instantiate an object load up the values to UPDATE or INSERT and once again voila.

Have looked but cannot see if this is available.

Comment: The reverse requires some work on your part e.g. `insert into {object->table} (name) values ({object->name})`.

Comment: Use hydrators / dehydrators instead, because of this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php#111744

Comment: @Axalix Pre-constructor value allocation is valuable for translating primitive data in the database to more useful data in the class (e.g. converting a datetime string into a `DateTime` object).

Comment: @Marty I prefer constructors to make its work (instantiation), when some properties may only be instantiated with the default values in the class, so I can see them when I open the file with this class. I am not a big fan of magic, when things happen implicitly (especially when you should fix a bug at 3am on production in someone's code).

Comment: @Axalix PHP is not a very good language choice if you're not a fan of magic :-P

Comment: Marty thanks but does that mean that each attribute/column has to be named or is that the whole table? Grateful for a slightly fleshed out answer as an answer can then give you the tick! Think this might be useful for others. The `FETCH_CLASS` is a fantastic boon for thrashing stuff around... In passing not using constructors at all at the moment but must be careful later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes. To some extent you can use something similar for insert or update.

But to achieve that, you have to learn [how to use PDO properly](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared). So, first we have to fix your select code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fixedTime WHERE transmissionProgramID = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$transmissionProgramID]);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'FixedTime');
$ftime = $stmt->fetch();
```

See - we are using prepared statements here, that you should be always using anyway. And at the same time that's the key for the [semi-]automation we can use with updates. Because with prepared statements you can use the object itself to provide values for the prepared query.

So, as long as you have object properties reflect table fields you can use a code like this:

```
$user = new stdClass();
$user->name = "foo";
$user->pass = "bar";

$sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, :name, :pass)";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute((array)$user);
```

But for the *real* automation you have to consider using an **ORM**, which is doing exactly what you're looking for. You can take a look at [Eloquent](http://daylerees.com/codebright-eloquent-orm/) for example. So, the code would be as simple and straightforward  as

```
$ftime = new fixedTime;
$ftime->value = time();
$ftime->save();
```